# how to create a docker image/container with same file rights as host user

Tags: docker

When start a docker container as user with name 'username1' in group 'usergroup1'.

And that container has files/folders on the local file system with volume:
eg.

```
$username1>docker run -v /homes/username1/output:output outputter
```

The files are created with root as owner.

What do i need to do in the Dockerfile or startup options to make sure the file rigths in the output folder are the same as the localuser:group, in this case username1:usergroup1?

Answer (score 7):

As explained in [this project](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Sharing-files-with-host-machine#avoiding-permission-changes-when-sharing-volumes):

> By default, our docker containers run as the root user. Files created or modified by the container will thus become owned by the `root` user, even after quitting the container.
>   **To avoid this problem, it is necessary to run the container using a non-root user**.
>
> If the host machine user has a UID other than 1000 (or 0, for root), the user should specify their UID when running docker, e.g.

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v $(pwd):/home/$USER/foo \
  -e USER=$USER  -e USERID=$UID rocker/rstudio
```

> to avoid changing the permissions in the linked volume on the host

Here that works because that [project Dockerfile](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/0ac97abf6579c4aa370bf3b760d250a047e1fe2d/rstudio/Dockerfile#L59-L67), when starting the container, [creates a user with the same uid](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/0ac97abf6579c4aa370bf3b760d250a047e1fe2d/rstudio/run.sh#L21-L28) (name is not important)

```
## (Docker cares only about uid, not username; diff users with same uid = confusion)
if [ "$USERID" -ne 1000 ]
## Configure user with a different USERID if requested.
    then
        echo "creating new $USER with UID $USERID"
        useradd -m $USER -u $USERID
        mkdir /home/$USER
        chown -R $USER /home/$USER
```

Comment: Even with ``--user`` option, you cant forward user name + UID, I am still using this trick! (some java program need an explicit user-name).

Comment: I am wondering why Docker doesnot do the same thing for /etc/passwd that they are doing for /etc/hosts :/ that will be a nice feature.

Comment: Is it necessary to use the `-P` flag? That publishes all ports "to random ports" (according to `man docker run`), which doesn't seem needed.

Comment: @Multihunter Good point. As seen here (https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Sharing-files-with-host-machine#windows), you can use a specific port instead of a random one. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to wait for [user namespace support](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/experimental/userns.md), hopefully later this year.

Comment: The reason I did not mention user namespace was because it allows for having "a unique range of user and group IDs which are *outside* the traditional user and group range utilized by the host system". I though the OP was after having the *same* uid as the host uid in his container.

Comment: link is broken!